# react native, how to paste text from clipboard into text input

Tags: javascript, react-native

currently i am using native base and having this type of text input for search bar

```
<Text>
   Card Name
</Text>
<Header searchBar rounded style={{ backgroundColor: '#E9E9EF'}}> 
   <Item style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgray', borderRadius: 5 }}>
      <Icon name="ios-search" />
      <Input placeholder="Search" onChangeText={(searchText) => this.setState({searchText})} value={this.state.searchText} />
   </Item>
</Header>
```

I wanted to enable paste from clipboard, where user can copy some text from other places and paste it on this search input box. How can i do that?

Comment: I answered in this post, please find I hope it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655600/enable-paste-and-selection-within-textinput-react-native/59875773#59875773

Comment: I answered in this post, I hope it will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655600/enable-paste-and-selection-within-textinput-react-native/59875773#59875773

Comment: I answered in this post, I hope it will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655600/enable-paste-and-selection-within-textinput-react-native/59875773#59875773

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clipboard API : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/clipboard
or Textinput property : selectTextOnFocus

```
<TextInput selectTextOnFocus={true} />
```

Comment: boolean jsx prop is fine like this `selectTextOnFocus`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this community package which is suggested by the official docs

> @react-native-clipboard/clipboard

```
import Clipboard from '@react-native-clipboard/clipboard'
```

You can easily access clipboard text by invoking an async function

```
const text = await Clipboard.getString()
```

Answer (score 0):

**If copy/paste not working for TextInput in react native. you can follow this code.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

    export class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: '', testWidth: '99%' };
      }
      componentDidMount() {

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ textboxWidth: '100%' })
        }, 100)
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
            <TextInput
              style={{ width: this.state.textboxWidth }}
              placeholder="Please type"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
              value={this.state.text}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution found in this Git reply worked much better for me: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18926#issuecomment-490541013

```
 <ScrollView
contentContainerStyle={Styles.contentContainerStyle}
keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
removeClippedSubviews={false}>

 <KeyboardAvoidingView>

      <Text style={Styles.labelPageTitle}>
        {'bla bla bla'}
      </Text>
      <Text>
          {'bla bla bla'}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ title: text })}
        style={Styles.textInput}
        value={title}
      />

</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0):

user RN gesture handler's TextInput instead of react native's 
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

do add the following
          selectTextOnFocus={true}
to the TexInput

Answer (score -8):

This is parameter in TextInput `secureTextEntry={true}` works

Comment: secureTextEntry masks the input. That is not an answer to ops question