# Hard to select TextInput entry in Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I don't know why its so hard to select the input in Android, I keep pressing the TextInput but the Select all, paste or copy option is not showing up whether the input is empty or not. In iOS it is working perfectly!

```
<View style={styles.reporterView}>
    <Text style={styles.reporterText}>Reporter:</Text>
       <TextInput
           value={this.state.reporter}
           onChangeText={(reporter) => this.setState({reporter})}
           style={styles.reporterField}
           placeholder={'Name'}
           autoCorrect={false}
           textAlign={'left'}
           maxLength={20}
           scrollEnabled={false}
       />
</View>
```

```
  reporterView: {
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    marginBottom: 25, 
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingLeft: '22%'
  },
  reporterField: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 22, 
    height: 55, 
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginTop: Platform.OS == 'android' ? -12 : 0
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a common issue with React-Native and Android. I found a solution from the support pages that seems to work quite well.

`removeClippedSubviews` is set as `true` by default. so you have to set this to `false`

These are possible paths to find this and set to false;

..\node_modules\react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs\node_modules\react-navigation-tabs\src\views\ResourceSavingScene.js

..\node_modules\react-navigation-tabs\src\views\ResourceSavingScene.js

..\node_modules\react-navigation-drawer\dist\view\ResourceSavingScene.js

..\node_modules\react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs\node_modules\react-navigation-tabs\dist\views\ResourceSavingScene.js

..\node_modules\react-native-paper\src\components\BottomNavigation.js

--

here is the code to use

```
removeClippedSubviews={
                 // On iOS, set removeClippedSubviews to true only when not focused
                 // This is an workaround for a bug where the clipped view never re-appears
                 Platform.OS === 'ios' ? navigationState.index !== index : true  //<--  set this to false
               }
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25038

Below are other solutions on Git and stackoverflow. Let me know if any of these help.

Stackoverflow: [Enable paste and selection within TextInput - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655600/enable-paste-and-selection-within-textinput-react-native)

Git: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20887